# Best server-side framework for heavy RIA based application?

Tags: java, python, ria

What do the collective beleive to be the best platform to use as a backend to **AJAX / Flex / Silverlight** applications and why?

We are undergoing a technology review and I would like to know some other opinions.

Is It **Java, Grails, Python, Rails, ColdFusion**, something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no definitive answer.** However, I would choose a light solution, like Python or Rails, over Java or ColdFusion.

You may want to investigate *C# ASP.NET + Silverlight* combo. Microsoft made it highly integrated, which is double-edged sword. But in many cases this helps.

You may also want to **review** existing solutions / applications / startups. Don't ditch PHP up front, there are many existing components for it. And don't overestimate the impact of server-side technology choice on success.